# Strikethrough or line-through text using sIFR

Tags: html, text, sifr

I am using sIFR3-r436. I want to strikethrough or line-through some text. I have tried both `<s>HTML</s>` and CSS: `text-decoration:line-through` but it won't work.

Here's my code.

```
css: ['.sIFR-root { font-size:28px;
line-height:36px; font-weight:bold;
color:#130f0e; text-align:center;
leading: 0; margin:0px; padding:0;
}','strong
{text-decoration:line-through;}']
```

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sIFR 3 is based on Flash 8, which I believe does not support `line-through`.